# Why is my Bootstrap column not centering its content?`

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following basic layout, in which to show a flash-card - the `detail-card`:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div id="cardContainer" class="col-md-4 text-center detail-card-container">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailCard", cardModel)        
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

I know I could just use `col-offset` but I have plans for the other two columns.

My vision here was to divide the page into three columns, give the middle one, `detail-card-container`, class `text-center` so that the content of that div should be horizontally centered inside it.

Yet when I start up the app, I get a display as follows:

[image: Non centered detail card]

The blue is the available space in the `detail-card-container` for the 'detail-card`, outlined in red. The detail card is fixed width 200, and the available space is about 400+ .This is displaying at the left of its available space, not in the centre as intended. The empty spaces to the left and right of the green in the image are the empty`col-md-4` divs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does parent div of `detail-card-container` has fixed width?

Comment: @phanther No, the parent div of `detail-card-container` is the view body, or `class="container body-content"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could give a specific `width`, `display: block`, plus `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto`.

Comment: Just what I was overlooking, thanks. I normally only use auto margins for `body` so it just never occurred to me a container is a container.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div class="col-md-4" align="center">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer my layout to be as CSS based as possible.